# Can we record audio and video call made by quickblox?

Tags: android, quickblox, call-recording

Is it possible to record audio call and video call made from quickblox?

This calls are voip calls made by using quick blox sdk integrated in my app.

Can we do it by normal call recording(in case of audio call) by using media recorder?

Does quickblox provide these recording facility?

Thanks.

Comment: check it -https://quickblox.com/blog/client-side-video-recording-with-new-ios-webrtc-sdk/

Comment: thanks, is there anything for android?

Comment: it takes the permission if record audio -https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK

Comment: @AD10 i have tried recording a qb audio call with mic and voice communication options, but in that case both parties on call can not hear each other's voice.